# PDO fetchAll() primary key as array group key

Tags: php, pdo

I want to store the contents of a specific database into an array, grouped by their primary keys. (Instead of the useless way PDO fetchAll() organises them).

My current code:

```
$DownloadsPDO = $database->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `downloads`");
$DownloadsArray =  $DownloadsPDO->execute();
$DownloadsArray =  $DownloadsPDO->fetchAll();
```

Which then outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 0 [0] => 0 [path] => /xx-xx/testfile.zip [1] => /xx-xx/testfile.zip [name] => Test Script [2] => Test Script [status] => 1 [3] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [0] => 1 [path] => /xx-xx/test--file.zip [1] => /xxxx/testfile.zip [name] => New Script-UPDATE [2] => New Script-UPDATE [status] => 1 [3] => 1 ) )
```

I was considering to use `PDO::FETCH_PAIR`, however I will be very soon expanding the amount of data I want to be able to use on this script. This works currently, but when I start to expand the amount of downloads and more clients come into play, obviously the way the data is grouped causes an issue.

Is it possible for me to group each array by their primary key (which is id)?

Comment: Loop the results using `fetch()` instead.

Comment: I could do that.. but doesn't that defeat the purpose of even having a fetchAll() function? @hjpotter92

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I decided to just loop through the results with fetch() and enter them into an array as I go along, this is the code I have used and it works just fine:

```
$DownloadsPDO = $database->dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `downloads`");
$Array = array();
while ($d = $DownloadsPDO->fetch()) {
    $Array[$d['id']]["id"] = $d['id'];
    $Array[$d['id']]["name"] = $d['name'];
    $Array[$d['id']]["path"] = $d['path'];                          
}

// Outputs
Array ( [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Test Script [path] => /xxxx/testfile.zip ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => New Script-UPDATE [path] => /xxxx/testfile.zip ) )
```

Which uses the primary key (being id) as the name for the array key, and then adds the data into it.

Thought I would add this as the answer as this solved it, thanks to the guys that helped out and I hope this is helpful to anyone else hoping to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 23):

You can just use

```
$results = array_map('reset', $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

`PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` returns an array of arrays. The first column is used as the key, and then within key is an array of all the results for that key. However, in our scenario each key will only contain 1 row. `reset()` returns the first element in array, thus eliminating 1 level of nesting.

Answer (score 15):

This should yield what you are looking for :

```
$results = $pdos->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: but what if i still want to have primary key value in array of results and the same time i want this primary key to be the key of the record details itself ?
because this solution removes "id" from the results and makes it the key of results

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to point out the only solution that works for me:

`fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_GROUP|\PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Beware that this will strip the first column from the resultset. So the query must be:

`SELECT id_keyname AS arrkey, id_keyname, .... FROM ...`

Comment: **This is the best solution.** However, the bits of PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE contain PDO::FETCH_GROUP, so you should just specify `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still suggesting you to loop using `fetch()` method. Otherwise, you can use [`array_reduce()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to iterate over the array. A sample on [codepad is here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LTb4cs).

The code(in human readable form) will be:

```
$myFinalArray = array_reduce($myInputArray, function($returnArray, $temp) { 
    $temp2 = $temp['id']; 
    unset($temp['id']); 
    $returnArray[$temp2] = $temp; 
    return $returnArray;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> So, my question is; is it possible for me to group each array by their
>   primary key (which is id)

Off course, you have 2 options here: Either to change the query **or** parse a result-set.
So, I'm sure you don't want to change query itself, so I'd go with parsing result-set.

**Note:**
You should use prepared SQL statements when they make sense. If you want to bind some parameters then its OKAY. But in this case, you only want get get result-set, so `prepare()` and `fetch()` will be kinda overdo.

So, you have:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 0 [0] => 0 [path] => /xx-xx/testfile.zip [1] => /xx-xx/testfile.zip [name] => Test Script [2] => Test Script [status] => 1 [3] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [0] => 1 [path] => /xx-xx/test--file.zip [1] => /xxxx/testfile.zip [name] => New Script-UPDATE [2] => New Script-UPDATE [status] => 1 [3] => 1 ) )
```

And you want:

```
Array( [id] => Array('bar' => 'foo') ....)
```

Well, you can do something like this:

```
$stmt = $database->dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `downloads`");
$result = array();

foreach($stmt as $array){

  $result[$array['id']] = $array;
}


print_r($result); // Outputs: Array(Array('id' => Array(...)))
```