# Generating Sitemap External to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pdo

So, i've built an "external to wordpress" sitemap generator using PDO to query the wordpress database.

I have found (after a month) an issue with it tho that I am completely stumped on.
Parent -> Children links in it.  And of course this is generating 404's when on spidering because officially, the child pages don' exist.

The sites are setup with permalinks as `/%postname%/`

And the code is:

```
<?php

require dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-config.php';
define('SITE_URL' , 'http://www.theactualdomain.com/'); // Change this for the site to pull this for

header('Content-Type: text/xml');

echo GenerateSiteMap();

function GenerateSiteMap(){
    global $table_prefix;
    $dsn = array('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn[0], $dsn[1], $dsn[2]);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
    // Pages
    $sql = "SELECT a.`post_name` As Slug, a.`post_date` As Date FROM `".$table_prefix."posts` a WHERE a.`post_status` = 'publish' AND a.`post_type` = 'page'";
    $stmnt1 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt1->execute();
    $rs0 = $stmnt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // Posts    
    $sql = "SELECT a.`post_name` As Slug, a.`post_date` As Date FROM `".$table_prefix."posts` a WHERE a.`post_status` = 'publish' AND a.`post_type` = 'post'";
    $stmnt1 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt1->execute();
    $rs1 = $stmnt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // Categories
    $sql = "Select b.`slug` As Slug, NOW() As Date From `".$table_prefix."term_taxonomy` a Inner Join `".$table_prefix."terms` b On b.`term_id` = a.`term_id` Where a.`taxonomy` = 'category' AND a.`count` > 0";
    $stmnt1 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt1->execute();
    $rs2 = $stmnt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // Tags
    $sql = "Select b.`slug` As Slug, NOW() As Date From `".$table_prefix."term_taxonomy` a Inner Join `".$table_prefix."terms` b On b.`term_id` = a.`term_id` Where a.`taxonomy` = 'post_tag' AND a.`count` > 0";
    $stmnt1 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt1->execute();
    $rs3 = $stmnt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // Archives
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(`post_date`, '%Y'), '/', DATE_FORMAT(`post_date`, '%m')) As Slug, NOW() As Date FROM `".$table_prefix."posts` WHERE `post_status` = 'publish' AND `post_type` = 'post'";
    $stmnt1 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt1->execute();
    $rs4 = $stmnt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $dbh = null;$dsn = null;$sql = null;$stmnt1 = null;
    unset($dbh, $dsn, $stmnt1, $sql);
    // Home Page and Sitemap Starter
    $ret = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" 
                        xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">    
                    <url>
                        <loc>' . SITE_URL . '</loc>
                        <lastmod>' . date('c',time()) . '</lastmod>
                        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
                        <priority>1.0</priority>
                    </url>';
    // Pages
    $ret .= FormatMapping($rs0, 'weekly', '1.0', 4);
    unset($rs0);
    // Posts
    $ret .= FormatMapping($rs1, 'weekly', '0.9', 0);
    unset($rs1);
    // Categories
    $ret .= FormatMapping($rs2, 'daily', '0.8', 1);
    unset($rs2);
    // Tags
    $ret .= FormatMapping($rs3, 'daily', '0.8', 2);
    unset($rs3);
    // Archives
    $ret .= FormatMapping($rs4, 'monthly', '0.7', 3);
    unset($rs4);
    $ret .= '</urlset>';
    return $ret;
}

function FormatMapping($rs, $cf = 'daily', $priority = '0.5', $type = 0){
    $ret = '';
    $url = '';
    $rCt = count($rs);
    for($i = 0; $i < $rCt; ++$i){
        $ret .= '<url>';
        switch($type){
            case 0: // Posts
            case 3: // Archives
            case 4: // Pages
                $url = SITE_URL . $rs[$i]['Slug'];
                break;  
            case 1: // Categories
                $url = SITE_URL . 'category/' . $rs[$i]['Slug'];
                break;
            case 2: // Tags
                $url = SITE_URL . 'tag/' . $rs[$i]['Slug'];
                break;
        }
        $ret .= '   <loc>' . $url . '</loc>
                    <lastmod>' . date('c', strtotime($rs[$i]['Date'])) . '</lastmod>
                    <changefreq>' . $cf . '</changefreq>
                    <priority>' . $priority . '</priority>
                </url>';
    }
    unset($rs);
    return $ret;
}
```

How can I set that initial `Page` query up to render the links properly?

No, using the Wordpress object is not a solution.  The whole point is to lessen the load on already heavy traffic sites, when applying the sitemap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your child page URLs are incorrect, because they should be of the form `<SITE_URL><parent_slug><child_slug>`, and your code is just returning `<SITE_URL><child_slug>`.  To get the full URL, you need to use the `post_parent` column of the `wp_posts` table and recursively build up the URL (as there could be several levels of nesting).

The following changes to your code seem to work:

Replace

```
// Pages
$sql = "SELECT a.`post_name` As Slug, a.`post_date` As Date FROM `".$table_prefix."posts` a WHERE a.`post_status` = 'publish' AND a.`post_type` = 'page'";
```

with

```
// Pages
$sql = "SELECT a.`id`, a.`post_name` As Slug, a.`post_date` As Date, a.`post_parent` FROM `".$table_prefix."posts` a WHERE a.`post_status` = 'publish' AND a.`post_type` = 'page'";
```

That gives you page and parent IDs, which you need to make the association.

Replace

```
$rs0 = $stmnt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

with

```
$rs0 = array_map('reset', $stmnt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

See [PDO fetchAll() primary key as array group key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754461/pdo-fetchall-primary-key-as-array-group-key) for an explanation of that one, but it makes the keys of the `$rs0` array the page IDs, which makes looking up the parent's slug much easier.

Add the function to (recursively) get the ancestor slugs:

```
function GetPageSlug($rs, $page_id) {
    if ($page_id == 0) {
        return '';
    }

    return GetPageSlug($rs, $rs[$page_id]['post_parent']) . $rs[$page_id]['Slug'] . '/';
}
```

Replace

```
$rCt = count($rs);
for($i = 0; $i < $rCt; ++$i){
```

with

```
foreach($rs as $i => $element) {
```

Since the IDs are page IDs, we can't assume they go from 0 to `count($rs)`.  I haven't changed the code to use `$element` instead of `$rs[$i]`, but you could.  I wanted to keep my changes to a minimum.

Finally, replace

```
case 4: // Pages
    $url = SITE_URL . $rs[$i]['Slug'];
```

with

```
case 4: // Pages
    $url = SITE_URL . GetPageSlug($rs, $rs[$i]['post_parent']) . $rs[$i]['Slug'];
```

---

The final code:

```
<?php

require dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-config.php';
define('SITE_URL' , 'http://www.theactualdomain.com/'); // Change this for the site to pull this for

header('Content-Type: text/xml');

echo GenerateSiteMap();

function GenerateSiteMap(){
    global $table_prefix;
    $dsn = array('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn[0], $dsn[1], $dsn[2]);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
    // Pages
    $sql = "SELECT a.`id`, a.`post_name` As Slug, a.`post_date` As Date, a.`post_parent` FROM `".$table_prefix."posts` a WHERE a.`post_status` = 'publish' AND a.`post_type` = 'page'";
    $stmnt1 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt1->execute();
    $rs0 = array_map('reset', $stmnt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754461/pdo-fetchall-primary-key-as-array-group-key
    // Posts    
    $sql = "SELECT a.`post_name` As Slug, a.`post_date` As Date FROM `".$table_prefix."posts` a WHERE a.`post_status` = 'publish' AND a.`post_type` = 'post'";
    $stmnt1 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt1->execute();
    $rs1 = $stmnt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // Categories
    $sql = "Select b.`slug` As Slug, NOW() As Date From `".$table_prefix."term_taxonomy` a Inner Join `".$table_prefix."terms` b On b.`term_id` = a.`term_id` Where a.`taxonomy` = 'category' AND a.`count` > 0";
    $stmnt1 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt1->execute();
    $rs2 = $stmnt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // Tags
    $sql = "Select b.`slug` As Slug, NOW() As Date From `".$table_prefix."term_taxonomy` a Inner Join `".$table_prefix."terms` b On b.`term_id` = a.`term_id` Where a.`taxonomy` = 'post_tag' AND a.`count` > 0";
    $stmnt1 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt1->execute();
    $rs3 = $stmnt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // Archives
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(`post_date`, '%Y'), '/', DATE_FORMAT(`post_date`, '%m')) As Slug, NOW() As Date FROM `".$table_prefix."posts` WHERE `post_status` = 'publish' AND `post_type` = 'post'";
    $stmnt1 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt1->execute();
    $rs4 = $stmnt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $dbh = null;$dsn = null;$sql = null;$stmnt1 = null;
    unset($dbh, $dsn, $stmnt1, $sql);
    // Home Page and Sitemap Starter
    $ret = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" 
                        xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">    
                    <url>
                        <loc>' . SITE_URL . '</loc>
                        <lastmod>' . date('c',time()) . '</lastmod>
                        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
                        <priority>1.0</priority>
                    </url>';
    // Pages
    $ret .= FormatMapping($rs0, 'weekly', '1.0', 4);
    unset($rs0);
    // Posts
    $ret .= FormatMapping($rs1, 'weekly', '0.9', 0);
    unset($rs1);
    // Categories
    $ret .= FormatMapping($rs2, 'daily', '0.8', 1);
    unset($rs2);
    // Tags
    $ret .= FormatMapping($rs3, 'daily', '0.8', 2);
    unset($rs3);
    // Archives
    $ret .= FormatMapping($rs4, 'monthly', '0.7', 3);
    unset($rs4);
    $ret .= '</urlset>';
    return $ret;
}

function GetPageSlug($rs, $page_id) {
    if ($page_id == 0) {
        return '';
    }

    return GetPageSlug($rs, $rs[$page_id]['post_parent']) . $rs[$page_id]['Slug'] . '/';
}

function FormatMapping($rs, $cf = 'daily', $priority = '0.5', $type = 0){
    $ret = '';
    $url = '';
    foreach($rs as $i => $element) {
        $ret .= '<url>';
        switch($type){
            case 0: // Posts
            case 3: // Archives
            case 4: // Pages
                $url = SITE_URL . GetPageSlug($rs, $rs[$i]['post_parent']) . $rs[$i]['Slug'];
                break;  
            case 1: // Categories
                $url = SITE_URL . 'category/' . $rs[$i]['Slug'];
                break;
            case 2: // Tags
                $url = SITE_URL . 'tag/' . $rs[$i]['Slug'];
                break;
        }
        $ret .= '   <loc>' . $url . '</loc>
                    <lastmod>' . date('c', strtotime($rs[$i]['Date'])) . '</lastmod>
                    <changefreq>' . $cf . '</changefreq>
                    <priority>' . $priority . '</priority>
                </url>';
    }
    unset($rs);
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks a ton

Comment: No worries; happy to help