# Use a column as array key

Tags: php, pdo

I want to use a column with numbers as array key.

I use a loop after fetchAll but I would like to know if is it possible to make it direclty.

My query:

```
$RequeteSql = $db->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM PouvoirsNumeros
        LEFT JOIN Pouvoirs ON (Pouvoirs.Pouvoir_Id = PouvoirsNumeros.Pouvoir_Id)
    WHERE
        PouvoirsNumeros.TypePerso = 'Ange'
    ORDER BY
        Pouvoirs.Pouvoir_Nom");
$ResultatRequete = $RequeteSql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

With it, I have:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [TypePerso] => Ange
            [Numero_Des] => 711
            [Pouvoir_Id] => 157
            ...
        )
...
)
```

I would like to replace the key with `Pouvoir_Id`:

```
(
    [157] => Array
        (
            [TypePerso] => Ange
            [Numero_Des] => 711
            [Pouvoir_Id] => 157
            ...
        )
...
)
```

With `PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`:

```
(
    [157] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [TypePerso] => Ange
                    [Numero_Des] => 711
                    [Pouvoir_Id] => 157
                    ...
                )
        )
...
)
```

Is it possible to make it directly with PDO ?

Comment: I suppose you can't do it with PDO, only with iterating over results and rebuilding your array.

Comment: I don't think PDO can handle it for you. But you can do it yourself with a one liner without any manual foreach loops using [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). [Here's an answer about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30129101/2453432)

Comment: And if you select only __two__ fields `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this will work...

```
$RequeteSql = $db->query("
    SELECT Pouvoir_Id as ind, TypePerso, Numero_Des, Pouvoir_Id
    FROM PouvoirsNumeros
        LEFT JOIN Pouvoirs ON (Pouvoirs.Pouvoir_Id = PouvoirsNumeros.Pouvoir_Id)
    WHERE
        PouvoirsNumeros.TypePerso = 'Ange'
    ORDER BY
        Pouvoirs.Pouvoir_Nom");
$ResultatRequete = $RequeteSql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I'll delete it when I can find the dupe.

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36621058/1839439 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/29682177/1839439

Comment: Thank you ! It's working ! :)
I have tried **PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC** but without start the select by the ID.